# Connect to vagrant from docker via php

Tags: php, docker

I've launched an API-server on vagrant in private network associated with ip `192.168.50.4`. In my `/etc/hosts` I've associated this ip with `api.project.dev` host. I can connect to `api.project.dev` outside of the VM (using browser, for example).

Also, I've launched an application on docker that tries to connect to the api on `api.dev`:

`docker run --rm -v "$PWD":/worker -w /worker yproximite/php7-cli php -r "echo file_get_contents('http://api.project.dev');"`

But it can't receive a response and I have `PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(http://127.0.53.53): failed to open stream: Connection refused in Command line code on line 1`. At the same time, it works bypassing php, via `ping`:

```
docker run --rm -v "$PWD":/worker -w /worker yproximite/php7-cli ping api.project.dev
PING api.project.dev (127.0.53.53): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 127.0.53.53: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.048 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.53.53: seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.074 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.53.53: seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.085 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.53.53: seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.065 ms
^C
--- api.project.dev ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.048/0.068/0.085 ms
```

How I can make php work the same way like `ping`?

---

Vagrant: `1.9.1`
VirtualBox: `5.1.14 r112924 (Qt5.6.2)`
Docker: `1.13.1, build 092cba3`
macOS: `Sierra 10.12.3 (16D32)`

---

**Update:** I can access to my host adding `--add-host=api.project.dev:192.168.50.4`:

`docker run --add-host=api.project.dev:192.168.50.4 --rm -v "$PWD":/worker -w /worker yproximite/php7-cli php -r "echo file_get_contents('http://api.project.dev');"`

Is it possible add external hosts from `/etc/hosts` to `/etc/hosts` of docker?